# Processing CSV data

Tags: excel, csv

I have recently been asked to take a .csv file that looks like this:

[image]

Into something like this:

[image]

Keeping in mind that there will be hundreds, if not thousands of rows due to a new row being created every time a user logs in/out, and there will be more than simply two users. My first thought was to load the .csv file into a MySQL then run a query on it. However, I really don't want to install MySQL on the machine that will be used for this.

I could do it manually for each agent in Ecxel/Open Office, but due to there being little room for error, and there are so many lines to do this, I want to automate the process. What's the best way to go about that?

Comment: SQLite would be fine and all, I am just trying to avoid using a database.

Really I was hoping there was a function in Excel, or any program that can handle .csv, to be able to do this quickly and easily.

Comment: Well, remember that excel has a rather small limit so having thousands of rows could reach that limit. A database is built to manage that amount of data and it would be death simple to create a script to add a new row.

Comment: I don't just need to add a new row. Really I just need each agent's name, username, date, and duration on one line. Parse out all of the other information, and just calculate the duration of each agent's time, and output to a new .csv file.

It would be pretty easy with a simple query in MySQL, although I can't say I have use SQLite enough to work with it. Probably not difficult, I am just on a tight deadline, and was hoping that there was a simple/quick way to get it done.

Comment: Are you grouping by agent name (1 output row for each agent) or date (1 row for each date for each agent)?

Comment: Agent name. This is a daily report, so agents name is all that is really important, but the date is left just to make for less confusion to the ones who will be viewing and using the file.

Comment: In my opinion, using a database is a good solution and it's easier than dealing with csv directly but it can be a matter of preferences. SQlite is almost exactly the same than MySQL so you probably won't have issues there.

Comment: I will definitely check into SQLite. I was under the assumptiont hat there was a large difference in the query language.

Comment: You could probably do that in about 10 or 20 lines of python. http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2091-python-read-and-write-csv-files http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Python, but if it's such short code, it might be worth looking into.

Comment: You can use a pivot table in Excel for this.

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner relies only on `awk`, and `date` for converting back and forth to timestamps:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{au=$1 "," $2;t=$4; \
 "date -u -d \""t"\"  +%s"|getline ts; sum[au]+=ts;}END \
 {for (a in sum){"date -u -d \"@"sum[a]"\" +%T"|getline h; print a,h}}' test.csv
```

having test.csv like this:

```
Agent,Username,Project,Duration
AAA,aaa,NBM,02:09:06
AAA,aaa,NBM,00:15:01
BBB,bbb,NBM,04:14:24
AAA,aaa,NBM,00:00:16
BBB,bbb,NBM,00:45:19
CCC,ccc,NDB,00:00:01
```

results in:

```
CCC,ccc,00:00:01
BBB,bbb,04:59:43
AAA,aaa,02:24:23
```

You can use this with little adjustments for extracting the date from extra columns.

Comment: +1 I am going to have to look at `awk`. That is quite remarkable.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example in case you decide to use SQLite. You didn't specify a language but I will use Python because it can be read as pseudocode. This part creates your sqlite file:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.Connection('my_sqlite_file.sqlite')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE "mytable" ("field1" varchar, \
    "field2" varchar, "field3" varchar);')
```

and you use the command:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO stackoverflow VALUES (?, ?, ?)', list_of_values)
```

to insert rows in your database once you have read them from the csv file. Notice that we only created three fields in the database so we are only inserting 3 values from your `list_of_values`. That's why we are using `(?, ?, ?)`.